# ajax-php works on localhost but not on realhost

Tags: php, ajax, json

This code works on localhost  but not on real, chrome developer tools showing that value is send, and Status Code:200 OK. but that value is not reaching php page.
On mozilla developer tools saying that json.PARSE:unexpected none-whitespace. But there is nothing before and after like text or whitespace.
All my files in  the same folder.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // sending id from portfolio to ajax for display modal carousel
    $('.view').on('click', function(e){

        var id2 = $(this).find('a').attr('id');

        $('.getValueHere').empty(); // empty the div before fetching and adding new data

       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajax.php",
       data: { 'id': id2 },
       success: function(data){
            $('.getValueHere').append(data.result);
       },
       error: function(){
           alert("error");
       }
     });

});
```

});

and here is for php page

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
 include_once("database/db.php"); 
    $db = new connection();
    $db = $db->dbConnection();

    /*******************************************************************
    *   This is for ADD new image on ADD image page, creating image with ajax   
    *   portfolio carousel img 
    ********************************************************************/


    $id = $_POST["id"]; // this post id never comes here



    $check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM website_articles where id='".$id."'");
        $check->execute();

            $result = array();

            while($row = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

                // SLIDE IMAGE
                $image = $row['img_url_slider'];

                $image = explode(',',$image);

                // SLIDE TECHNIQS

                $tech = $row['teknologies'];

                $tech = explode(',',$tech);


                $name = $row['article_name'];

                $desc = $row['article_description'];

                $result['result'] ="";


                    $result['result'] .= '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel" style="margin-left:15px;">'.$name.'</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">                                 
                                <div class="wrapper" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
                                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                      <!-- Indicators -->
                                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">';
                                        for($i=0; $i<count($image); $i++){
                                             if($i == 0){
                                                $result['result'] .= '<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class="active"></li>';
                                              }else{
                                                $result['result'] .= '<li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="'.$i.'" class=""></li>';
                                              }
                                        }

                                     $result['result'] .= '</ol>
                                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox"> ';
                                      for($i=0; $i<count($image); $i++){
                                          if($i == 0){
                                                $result['result'] .='
                                                <div class="item active">
                                                    <img src="'.@$image[0].'" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                                                    <div class="carousel-caption"> </div>
                                                </div>';
                                          }else{
                                                $result['result'] .='
                                                <div class="item">
                                                    <img src="'.@$image[$i].'" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
                                                    <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
                                                </div>';
                                          }

                                      }
                                     $result['result'] .= '</div>

                                      <!-- Controls -->
                                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                      </a>
                                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                                      </a>
                                    </div><!-- /carousel-->
                                </div>  
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">  
                                    <h3>Technologies</h3>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled checkList">';
                                    for($i=0; $i<count($tech); $i++){                                       
                                        $result['result'] .= '<li><i class="fa fa-check"></i> '.$tech[$i].'</li>';                                              
                                    }
                                $result['result'] .= '</ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">  
                                    <h3>Description</h3>
                                    <p>'.html_entity_decode($desc).'</p>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- /row-->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <a type="button" href="'.$row['article_url'].'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">visit website</a>
                        </div>
                      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div>';
}

$result = json_encode($result);

echo $result;
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this and see if the error goes away.

```
html_entity_decode($desc)
```

If it goes away try:

```
html_entity_decode($desc,ENT_QUOTES)
```

Comment: i Just fixed this issue by removing this    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset-UTF-8;');  to   this header('Content-Type: application/json');  and problem is gone away, I don't know why this happends but it tokk many hours from me today.

Comment: You probably have description(s) with quote mark(s).

Comment: yes, you have right, I just change the code to you write ang took back header to old one, it's still working. Thank you very much for information, now I know.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your headers have already been set elsewhere. Have you tried commenting out the header to see if this solves the issue? Also enable php errors to display any hidden errors that are not allowing the code to continue. Hope this helps!